# jQuery Tools - Slideshow

Tags: jquery, flowplayer

I am trying to get familar with the jQuery Tools - Slideshow from Flowplayer (http://flowplayer.org/tools/tabs/slideshow.html). Has anybody a hint for me how to select e.g. tab2 as start default, or how to switch to another tab when starting?

Thanks in advance,

Juergen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://flowplayer.org/tools/tabs/index.html

look for `initialIndex` in the configuration property...

Comment: Hi Reigel,
thanks for this advice. Yes, 'initialIndex' was the missing magic word ;-)
Juergen

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".slidetabs").tabs(".images > div", {

    // enable "cross-fading" effect
    effect: 'fade',
    fadeOutSpeed: "slow",

    // start from the beginning after the last tab
    rotate: true,

//set your default tab
current: "tab_2" //class name

// use the slideshow plugin. It accepts its own configuration
}).slideshow();
```

Comment: Hi Flakron,
thanks for your help. The advice from Reigel with 'initialIndex' was the solution.
Juergen

Answer (score 0):

Hey You Should Read this
http://flowplayer.org/tools/documentation/scripting.html#events
its says about it and also 
http://flowplayer.org/tools/tabs/index.html is also saying

Comment: Hi Alex,
thanks for your help. The advice from Reigel with 'initialIndex' was the solution.
Juergen